# I am using MCP, but when I try to launch, it gives me a ClassLoader error?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, minecraft

I have setup MCP with IntelliJ IDEA but I have an issue, whenever I try to launch the game, I would have to keep trying until it works, I don't know if this will help but whenever it says Task :Compiling Java, Task :processResources, and Task :classes, then it would launch but when it doesn't then it won't launch. (BTW sorry if this is the wrong place to send this question)

I haven't really tried anything because I am new to IntelliJ and I am afraid that I might press a button that I don't know what it will do it might do something that I don't want because it has already happened once, and pressing things that you don't know what it will do is also just stupid, unless it is safe to do so.

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
joptsimple/OptionSpec
at Start.main(Start.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: joptsimple.OptionSpec
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 1 more
```

Comment: If you want to code, you have to understand the error. The error occurs in your Start class on line 11. The exception is a NoClassDefFoundError, that means that no definiton for a specific class is found, in your case that class is OptionSpec. The exception is described further [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html)

Comment: @Legacy I tried googling, but still have not clue what MCP could stand for (Master Control Program? if so, then what, cause the MCP would be JVM :) ). As the Mano176 said, the `OptionSpec` class can't be found on runtime. Since it's somekind of game you can't provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), but googling the class you are missing `joptsimple.OptionSpec' had lead me to the:
https://github.com/CyberdyneCC/Thermos/issues/136 where I think you could find your solution. Main thing is try googling more ;)

Comment: @itwasntme MCP stands for Mod Coder Pack, which is the decompiled source code for Minecraft, or at least I think.

Comment: You shouldn't be using MCP directly anyway. Either use Forge or whatever Bukkit is going by these days.

Comment: I know that I shouldn't, but when I ask people how to set it up, they say "If you don't know how to set it up, then maybe you shouldn't be trying it", and I just think, then I don't know what to do an this point, there aren't any tutorials that I can find.